# Django Rest Framework extend ModelSerializer.create()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Looking at the DRF source I could assume this would print "Hello World" to the console, when a new instance is created:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_attrs):
        print 'Hello World'
        return super(WorkshopLevelSerializer, self).create(validated_attrs)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel


serializer = MyModelSerializer(data=data, many=True, allow_add_remove=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

It does not. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Can you confirm the `if` condition is true and the code tries to call `save()`? (I looked into DRF source code, if your serializers instance is `None` (which is the default value), it should call `create`, else it calls `update`

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the many=True kwarg (https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L71). I can confirm that the instance does not exist in this case. I also tried to extend `update()` but my extended version of `update()` did not run either.